# How can I get the right side of my border array indexes to work?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating an array with ones and threes as the values for my indexes. I have twos to represent my borders. I've written four for loops to set up borders for my array. They all seem to work except for the for loop that creates the border for the right side.

```
value: 5

222222
213133
231133
211131
231331
222222


//Creates the border indexes for the cells represented by the value 2
    for (int top = 0; top < cells.length; top++)
        cells[0][top] = 2;

    for (int bottom = 0; bottom < cells.length; bottom++)
        cells[cells.length-1][bottom] = 2;

    for (int left = 0; left < cells.length; left++)
        cells[left][0] = 2;

    //for some reason, this code doesn't do anything
    for (int right = 0; right < cells.length; right++)
        cells[right][cells.length] = 2;


    // Creates the first generation of cells randomly
    for (int i = 1; i <m; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        {   
            double CellCreate = Math.random();
            if (CellCreate > .5)
            {
                cells[i][j] = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                cells[i][j] = 3;

            }   
        }
    }

            //Prints the cells  
    for (int x = 0; x < cells.length;x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < cells.length; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(cells[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, there is one thing iteresting here. The original loop didn't fail with an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`, so it is highly likely that there is something awry going on at declaring your array too. I should have failed, if the array was properly defined. You should post that too... It seems, that you declared your rows in the array to have `cells.length+1` elements

Otherwise, this is a classic loop ending problem, instead of `cells.length` in

```
    cells[right][cells.length] = 2;
```

you should use `cells.length-1`

```
for (int right = 0; right < cells.length; right++)
    cells[right][cells.length-1] = 2;
```

Other notes:

It is wise to always use the curly brackets to enclose the blocks of loops and if conditions:

```
//for some reason, this code doesn't do anything
for (int right = 0; right < cells.length; right++) {
    cells[right][cells.length-1] = 2;
}
```

This way it will be less likely you get into a "no-loop" situation like this:

```
/**** BAD!!! *****/
for(...); // note the ; !!! That ends the loop block
    doSomething(); //this will be done only once!
/**** BAD!!! *****/
```

Comment: I could've sworn I put cells.length-1 there. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to subtract 1 from `cells.length`:

```
for (int right = 0; right < cells.length; right++)
    cells[right][cells.length-1] = 2;
```